# Javascript object member returning undefined on Android

Tags: javascript, android, json, backbone.js, cordova

I'm creating a phonegap app using backbone.js. I'm saving to the database and getting an object resonse:

```
    match_user.save({
            'email':user.email,
            'password':password,
            'username':username,
            'facebook_login':'yes',
            'facebook_id':user.id
    }, 
    {
    success:function(data){
        console.log('data is ');
        console.log(data);

                console.log('data.username is ');
                console.log(data.username);

                console.log('data.password is ');
                console.log(data.password);

        console.log('JSON.stringify(data) is ');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));



        that.setSession(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        console.log('in the error');
    }
    });
```

The output of the console.log's in eclipse is:

```
    10-16 14:01:08.490: I/Web Console(10185): data is  
    10-16 14:01:08.490: I/Web Console(10185): [object Object]

            10-16 14:20:51.500: I/Web Console(11297): data.username is  
        10-16 14:20:51.505: I/Web Console(11297): undefined

        10-16 14:20:51.510: I/Web Console(11297): data.password is  
        10-16 14:20:51.510: I/Web Console(11297): undefined 

    10-16 14:01:08.495: I/Web Console(10185): JSON.stringify(data) is
    {"first_name":"",
    "last_name":"",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "username":"user5654401630",
    "password":"ipk9d",
    "facebook_login":"yes",
    "facebook_id":"5675685685"}
```

data.username, data.email etc all return "undefined", but I can see when I stringify the object that they have values...

Comment: seems that `data` is actually JSON, why are you trying to parse it?

Comment: I want to be able to do: var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.username);

Comment: `alert(data.username)` should work without parsing in this case

Comment: incredibly, i also get "undefined" for this too. I have edited the question to include that

Answer (score 1):

That's because JSON.stringify returns a string and you do not have the json as object anymore
So you need to get the data without stringying the same

```
 match_user.save({
            'email':user.email,
            'password':password,
            'username':username,
            'facebook_login':'yes',
            'facebook_id':user.id
    }, 
    {
    success:function(data){
        console.log('data is ');
        console.log(data);

        console.log('JSON.stringify(data) is ');
        console.log(data);

        console.log('JSON.stringify(data).username is ');
        console.log(data.username);

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('obj.username is ');
        console.log(obj.username);

        that.setSession(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        console.log('in the error');
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a backbone thing. data.username returned undefined but data.get('username') works.